# Make helm-recentf open files with external program?

Tags: helm, files, recentf, openwith

tl;dr Which keymap is active in `helm-recentf`? Or is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

I want to use emacs as my file browser. When I select a file with `helm-find-files` or `helm-recentf`, I want to check whether the extension is in a whitelist (eg. "pdf", "png", "docx") and if it is, open the file in the appropriate external program. If it's not, the file should be visited normally in emacs.

### Solutions I've rejected:

1. Use `C-c C-x` in helm to open candidate externally. I don't want to press a separate keybinding or to be prompted for a program name, I just want to press `return` as usual and have helm figure out the right thing to do.
2. Use the `openwith` package. It breaks things like mu4e attachments and images embedded in org buffers. I only ever want files I explicitly open through helm to be opened externally.

### What I've tried so far:

I remapped `RET` to a custom function that does what I want. It's probably a horrible hack, but it works for `helm-find-files`!

```
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "RET") 'my-helm-ff-run-open-in-emacs-or-externally)


(defun my-helm-ff-run-open-in-emacs-or-externally ()                                
  (interactive)                                                                     
  (with-helm-alive-p                                                                
    (helm-exit-and-execute-action 'my-helm-ff-open-in-emacs-or-externally)          
    )                                                                               
  )                                                                                 

(defun my-helm-ff-open-in-emacs-or-externally (file)                                
  ;; based on helm-open-file-externally,                                            
  ;; Copyright (C) 2012 ~ 2016 Thierry Volpiatto <thierry.volpiatto@gmail.com>      
  "Open FILE either with emacs or with an external program.                         
Try to guess which external program to use with `helm-get-default-program-for-file'.
If not found, open file in emacs."                                                  
  (if (bufferp file)                                                                
      (switch-to-buffer file)                                                       
    (let* ((file-name      (expand-file-name file))                                 
           (collection      (helm-external-commands-list-1 'sort))                  
           (default-program   (helm-get-default-program-for-file file-name)))       
      (if (not default-program)                                                     
          (find-file file) ;; open in emacs                                         
        (helm-run-or-raise default-program file) ;; open in external program        
        ))))
```

The only problem is, I can't define this mapping for `helm-recentf`. I assumed that the `helm-buffer-map` would be active in `helm-recentf`, but it's not:

```
(define-key helm-buffer-map (kbd "RET") '(lambda () (interactive) (message "define-key worked!")))
```

The message prints when I select a buffer in `helm-mini`, but not when I select a file in `helm-recentf`.

### Questions

So, which keymap is active in `helm-recentf`?

Or, am I doing this all wrong, and is there a much better to intelligently open some files with an external program?

Comment: Helm should prompt you *once* for an external program to open a file of a certain type, then use that program thereafter. Is it prompting you *every* time, even after you've specified the external program once already for, say, a PDF?

Comment: Also, [`helm-find-files-map`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-files.el#L374) is the map that's active when using `helm-find-files` and `helm-recentf`.

Comment: It doesn't prompt me more than once, but it doesn't allow me to open a file in emacs. So I'd still need to use 2 separate commands for external vs internal.

Comment: Are you sure about `helm-find-files-map`? When I bind something to RET in `helm-find-files-map`, like the message example above, it works in `helm-find-files` but not in `helm-recentf`.

Answer (score 1):

> Which keymap is active in helm-recentf?

It's `helm-generic-files-map`, inherits from the `helm-type-file` class.